# python: "missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'" 1 out of 3 times?

Tags: python, exception

Here is part of my code. Overall, I have a few thousand lines written (I know, way too ambitious for a 'newbie').

```
import sqlite3
from sqlite3 import Error

from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
mystack = []            # what is the current pathway thru the functions
its_bad = False
thecurse = None
user_dbconn = None
user_fulldb = 'c:\\mydata.sq3'
# -------------------------------------------------------
class The_DB():
    """Class for handling all database interaction."""
    global mystack
    global user_fulldb
    global thecurse

    def create_connection():
        """ create a database connection to a SQLite database. """
        try:
            user_dbconn = sqlite3.connect(user_fulldb)
            .thecurse = Global.user_dbconn.cursor()
        except Error as e:
            print('DB not connected: ', e)
            its_bad = True
        if mystack[len(mystack)-1] == 'Welcome_check_user_3':
            Welcome.check_user_4()
# ---------------------------------------------------------------
class Pop_it(Popup):
    global my_mess
    def open(self, *args, **kwargs):
        app=App.get_running_app()
        self.Opacity = 1
        super(Pop_it, self).open(*args, **kwargs)

    def dismissit(self):
        app=App.get_running_app()
        super(Pop_it, self).dismiss()

def show_popup():
    show = MessageBox()
    popupWindow = Popup(title = 'Attention', content =show, auto_dismiss = False, size_hint=(None,None), size=(400,400))
    popupWindow.open()
    return popupWindow
# --------------------------------------------------------------
class MessageBox(FloatLayout):
    global mystack
    mymessagebox = ObjectProperty()
    def close_up(self):
        if mystack[len(mystack)-1] == 'Welcome_create_user':
            Welcome.check_user_2()
        elif mystack[len(mystack)-1] == 'Welcome_create_user2':
            Welcome.check_user_3()
# -----------------------------------------------
class Welcome(Screen):
    """Class for the opening screen.
    global its_bad
    global mymess
    global mystack
    user_name = ''
    user_pass = ''
    def check_user(self):
        """ Validates information entered for an existing user.
        mystack.append('Welcome:check_user')
        its_bad = False
        self.user_name = self.tname.text
        if not configfile.has_section(self.user_name):
            my_mess = 'Unknown user'
            its_bad=True
            app = App.get_running_app()
            app.Popups = show_popup()
        self.check_user_2()
    def check_user_2(self):
        mystack.pop()
        mystack.append('Welcome:check_user_2')
        self.user_pass = self.tpass.text
        this_pass = configfile[user_name]['upass']
        if Global.user_pass == self.this_pass:
                pass
        else:
            my_mess = 'incorrect//missing password'
            its_bad=True
            app = App.get_running_app()
            app.Popups = show_popup()
        self.check_user_3()
    def check_user_3(self):
        mystack.pop()
        if its_bad:
            mystack.pop()
            return
        mystack.append('Welcome_check_user_3')
        users_path=configfile[user_name]['col1loc']
        user_dbname=configfile[user_name]['col1name']
        user_fulldb = os.path.join( users_path, user_dbname)
        The_DB.create_connection()
    def check_user_4(self):
        mystack.pop()
        mystack.append('Welcome_check_user_4')
        The_DB.get_control()
        mystack.pop()
        Global.theroot.current = 'scrMain'
```

When I run it, I get an "**TypeError: check_user_4() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'**" exception. This line appears in *The_DB.create_connection* method and appears to be the same syntax I'm using successfully in *Messagebox.close_up* and in *Welcome.check_user*. I have looked at postings for this exception, but still have no idea why it works someplaces and not the other. . .

Comment: The instance methods are bound to the object of the class

Comment: You are using classes very idiosyncratically. A lot of the time you're calling the methods in them as regular functions, via the class. That's not normally how things work with regular methods. You should be creating *instances* of your classes, which would also allow you to stop using so many global variables. It's probably impossible for us to diagnose your full issues here, as you have four or five syntax errors that I can see, which means you've not given us a [mcve].

Comment: Blcknght: Thank you for your reply. Looking into what you recommended ("creating instances" of my classes called for a few hours to wrap my head around what "instances" was all about. I now understand (I Hope) how it all works. To the point, I simply created an instance of the class Welcome and used that in tThe_DB.create_connection() and the code now works! Again, thanks. . . Brain